# Combine multiple workbooks to one workbook (Closed)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need to combine multiple workbook to one workbook.

Source workbooks have unique sheet name = "job"

Destination workbook have multiple sheets name

The Below code have 2 issues,

1. For loop not work
2. pasted data in Destination workbook create a new sheet. But i need to paste the data to existing sheet.

---

```
Sub combine()

'destination worksheets    
    Dim Ar As Worksheet
    Dim nr As Worksheet
    Set Ar = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetAr")
    Set nr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetnr")
    'Source workbooks
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FolderPath = Environ("userprofile" & "\Desktop\Copy")
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx*")
    
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim AW As Workbook
    
    Set AW = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Job")
    
     For Each AW In ws
     AW.Activate
     Cells.ShownAll
     ws.Copy Ar
     Next AW
     Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges = True
     Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub`
```

Comment: this might be better asked on stackoverflow

Comment: if it was answered there.. u may close this question here.. ( :